# Unable to extract page tittle and page_source using IEDriverServer and Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, webdriverwait, selenium-iedriver

i have just started selenium coding.
i have python 3.6.6, executing following code on jupyter notebook (with chrome broser)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\Python 36\\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.get('https://google.com')

print(driver.title)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.close()
```

this is giving following output:

WebDriver
WebDriverThis is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.

In this process an IE browser gets open and goes to google.com (any desired site) but not getting closed

Comment: It might be a timing issue. The page is not fully loaded and the title is not set when you're trying to get the title. You could apply [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for the page title to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the *Page Titile* and the *Page Source* you need to:

- Invoke the *FQDN* i.e `https://www.google.com/` through `get()`, i.e. including `www`.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) for a clickable *WebElement* to be interactive.
- While ending your program invoke `quit()` instead of `close()`.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\Python 36\\IEDriverServer.exe")
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  print(driver.title)
  print(driver.page_source)
  driver.quit()
  ```